# How can i hide runtime error dialog in android?

Tags: android, dialog, runtime-error

The runtime error dialog is prompted when error occurs in android. Is it possible to hide it?
Someone can help me?

Comment: Use exception handling method..

Answer (score 1):

For some errors you can use "try-catch" block, but unfortunately, not all errors/exceptions are catchable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to know which part of your code that might cause the error.
Then surround that part with **try** and **catch**:

```
try{
    //your codes that cause error
    //line 1
    //line 2
    //line 3
    //...
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace(); //to trace the error
    //what to do if error occurred
    //line 1
    //line 2
    //line 3
    //...
}
```